# Codecademy Battleship! Python

Tags: python

This is the "Battleship!" problem that is covered in Codecademy (Python) I want to put a condition wherein the number of turns does not get incremented in the case that the user enterers a value of row/column that is repeated or outside limits. I can't figure out what the problem is in this code:

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Let's play Battleship!"
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
print ship_row
print ship_col

# Everything from here on should go in your for loop!
for turn in range(4):
    # Be sure to indent four spaces!
    print "Turn", turn + 1
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
        break
    else:
        if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
            print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
            print "Please try again."
#            turn -= 1                                        Why doesn't this work? The "Game Over" message does not get displayed at the end of the game if such a case arises (but the game still ends!), which means the value of turn does not reach 3. But still when 'turn + 1' is printed, the value gets incremented even if such a condition is encountered. 
        elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
            print "You guessed that one already."
            print "Please try again."
#            turn -= 1                                        Same as last message.
        else:
            print "You missed my battleship!"
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
        if turn == 3:
            print "Game Over"
        # Print (turn + 1) here!
        print_board(board)
```

Comment: Would you like us to read all that code, run it and test it for you?

Comment: Please read [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be very easy to strip this whole thing down to its essentials. For example, see [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/YTst1vC3). If you're given us that, instead of your whole program, I'll bet your question would be voted +3 instead of -5 with 2 close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only a very small error in your code, from what I can see. The last if statement, which includes your "Game Over" string, is indented incorrectly. Move it left one block:

```
  else:
    print "You missed my battleship!"
    board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"

if turn == 3:
  print "Game Over"
  # Print (turn + 1) here!
  print_board(board)
```

Here is my complete code from that exercise:

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Let's play Battleship!"
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
print ship_row
print ship_col

for turn in range(4):
    print "Turn", turn + 1

    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
    else:
        if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
            print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
        elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
            print "You guessed that one already."
        else:
            print "You missed my battleship!"
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"

        print_board(board)

    if turn == 3:
        print "Game Over"
```

Comment: You missed the "break" after printing "Game Over:

Answer (score 1):

A `for turn in range(4):` loop doesn't work the way you think it does.

It's equivalent to this:

```
_range = [0, 1, 2, 3]
_it = iter(_range)
 while True:
    try:
        turn = next(_it)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    # your code here
```

You don't have to understand all of the details there, but they key point is that, each time through the loop, it's assigning a new value to `turn`, which comes straight out of the iterator, and has nothing to do with the old value of `turn`. So, your changes to `turn` are irrelevant.

---

So, how do you fix it?

One way is to replace the `for` loop with a `while` loop that explicitly maintains `turn`, so you can explicitly decrement it—or, better, just not increment it. For example:

```
turn = 0
while turn < 4:
    # your code, slightly modified
    # do turn += 1 only when the turn is valid
    # don't do turn += 1 when the turn is invalid
```

The other way is to put another loop inside this `for` loop that just repeats until the player makes a valid turn:

```
for turn in range(4):
    while True:
        # your code, slightly modified
        # do break only when the turn is valid
        # do nothing, or continue, when the turn is invalid
```

---

While I'm at it, there's another problem in your code.

That `if turn == 3` part is either wrong, or unnecessary. The game is over when the player is out of turns. You know the player is out of turns when you finish the loop. You don't need any extra test for it. So:

```
for or while or whatever:
    # stuff    
print "Game Over"
```